# Did some White House staffers organize themselves to call for ceasefire in Gaza?

Tags: politics, media, gaza

This [TikTok post](https://www.tiktok.com/@emma_pike_/video/7340065141414743339) claims some WH staffers **organized themselves** to protest the US administration's handling of the Gaza war and published a statement to that effect. The alleged statement mentions Aaron Bushnell, the Air Force member who self-immolated to protest the war, and contains some strong statements such as "Biden our commander-in-chief continues to ignore staff dissent over the mass suffering caused by our leaders’ complicity"

I searched multiple mainstream news websites and found no mention of such statement. I did find some fringe websites and social media posts repeating similar claims, but nothing on mainstream media.
It seems to me that if such an event took place, it would be considered newsworthy.

My question: Is there proof that some White House staffers organize themselves to call for ceasefire in Gaza and criticize the administration? I am **not** asking about individual opinions from staffers regarding this topic, but whether they actually issued such a statement as a group, either listing their names, or hiding their individual identities.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not, or equivalent to no.

From what best I could find, the source for this is from [this anonymous tweet](https://twitter.com/DWS________/status/1762199630517764585/). The picture of the statement in question doesn't have any names, position or any other identifiable information to allow someone to authenticate the statement.

This is especially noticeable in light of previous dissenting voices that were anonymous but did have a way to authenticate that they were who they claim to be either by coming to a vigil in front of the white house:

[Biden administration staffers call for ceasefire at vigil outside White House](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/12/13/politics/biden-staffers-ceasefire-vigil-white-house/index.html)

> More than three dozen people, including political appointees, administration staffers and civil service career staff, attended the early evening vigil in front of the White House. The participants wore sunglasses and masks to conceal their identities.
>
> Josh Paul, a former State Department official who resigned from his job in October over disagreement with the Biden administration’s approach to the Israel-Hamas war, delivered opening remarks. A former administration staffer also read a statement given to him by a group of Palestinian administration officials who did not want to be identified.

Or by using a reputable source to publish their :

[Dear President Biden, we need a ceasefire now.](https://medium.com/@BidenHQforCeasefireNow/dear-president-biden-we-need-a-ceasefire-now-f48b732b2433)

As a side note, this is an extremely cynical take which says "We praise this man who gave his life to a cause, but are not willing to risk our cushy job for it".

Comment: In a less cynical way, if burning yourself to death is not going to merit even a mention by the White House, why losing my job is going to make anything but hurting myself? And in a country where your healthcare is tied to your job, that's a high risk to gamble with.

Comment: @Rekesoft because an anonymous letter is worthless. There is no way to know who did it and how many people stand behind it. It can be a letter signed by all the staffers in the campaign, including all high  ranking individuals, and it can be made by a Russian propogandist from Moscow with no support in the white house staff. Even if it was real, it has no power behind it. They call for a cease fire, but how are they going to advance it? They will not quit, and continue business as usual. They give no reason for anyone to listen to them.